# Who to add a line break in wordpress 'the_date'?

Tags: wordpress

I have this line:

```
<?php the_date(' F j Y')?>
```

this ends up with `June 13 2012` (the current date). I would like to have the year on another line. I have tried this:

```
<?php the_date(' F j <br /> Y')?>
```

But it does not work. is there a way to get that break in between.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the components of the date when you call the function. The 'f', 'j', 'Y', et. al essentially get replaced by the date, so omitting the 'Y' will allow you to specify it in another function call after the line break.

```php
echo get_the_date('F j');
echo '<br />';
echo get_the_date('Y');
```

Wordpress actually has a nice guide explaining format characters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

EDIT: Fixed to use `get_the_date` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the date function but you can use `substr()` to break out what you want here's an example;

```
$date = the_date(' F j Y'); // in your example it should return : "June 13 2012"
echo substr($date,0,(count($temp)-5)); //this will echo just "June 13"
echo "<br />";
echo substr($date,-4,4); //This will echo just the year
```

Which will display;

```
    June 13 
    2012
```